# Accent Colour not showing in the document browser in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, appkit

I am trying to build a document based app & the document browser is not showing the accent colour I want for iOS but on macOS it shows the correct accent colour, in which in this case orange, it is programmed to automatically open the document browser on launch (at least for now but have plans to have the app bring up the document browser with the press of a button) this is the code as it stands now.

```
DocumentGroup(newDocument: text_Document()) { file in
    ContentView(document: file.$document)
}
```

The app uses SwiftUI & I plan on just using UIKit & Appkit for the document browser.

I have been doing SwiftUI up until this point & I tried to make SwiftUI & UIKit as well as AppKit work together to make the whole document browser what ever accent colour I want for the App because the `DocumentGroup` won't open with the accent colour I want, so I am having to flock to UIKit & Appkit for that.